# why "this" pointer is not needed when calling virtual function with pointer-to-function?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, virtual-functions

example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "A::print" << std::endl; }
}
```

what I know:
we can call member functions with pointer-to-member-function and an object, so this would work

```
typedef void (A::*fptr)(); //pointer-to-member-function
fptr p = &A::print;
A a;
(a.*p)(); // prints "A::print"
```

but it seems like I can call A::print with a pointer-to-function without an object:

```
typedef void (*fptr)();
long *vptr; // pointer to virtual table
fptr func;  // pointer-to-function

vptr = (long*)(&a);
func = (fptr)( *(long*)(*vptr) ) // pointer to first function in virtual table
func(); // prints "A::print"
```

my question is why does this work? Do we not need a "this" pointer to call virtual function?

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour by accessing objects through pointers of unrelated types. Anything can happen.

Comment: A lot of stuff can "work" by (lack of) luck.

Answer (score 1):

It works in this case because your print function doesn't access any class member variables, which implies that the function does not need to use 'this' for it's execution, and that's the reason it works.

It would fail horribly if the method in question relied on any member variables.

If you consider the asm for the following methods:

```cpp
void func1() { return; }
struct Foo {
  void func2() { return; }
};
```

In both cases they'd simply boil down to:

```
  ret
```

Adding in a print statement there:

```cpp
void func1() { printf("hello world"); }
struct Foo {
  void func2() { printf("hello world"); }
};
```

The asm for both would now look like:

```
  call printf
  ret
```

So whilst you are using the wrong calling convention to call the method in the second case, it's not a big deal in this case (because this is never used)

Comment: You missed the important words in the question: **virtual function**. It's assumed that `this` is used.

Comment: @S.M. What do you mean?

Comment: @curiuosguy The pointer to the virtual table is placed near `*this`, thus it's used to get get the virtual table.